# Richfaces TabPanel - Avoid multiple submission when user double click on a tab

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Let's consider this code sample:

```
<rich:tabPanel switchType="ajax">
    <rich:tab label="tab1">
        ...
    </rich:tab>
    <rich:tab label="tab2">
        ...
    </rich:tab>
</rich:tabPanel>
```

This will create a simple tab panel with 2 tabs, the content of the `<rich:tabPanel>` is refreshed using Ajax.

So if I am on `tab1` and I click on `tab2`, an Ajax request is sent to the server to get the `tab2` content. My concern is that if the user double clicks on `tab2`, then **two** Ajax requests will be sent (there will be in fact as many requests sent as the number of times the user quickly clicks on this tab header).

So my question is how to avoid having multiple requests sent, even if the user clicks several times on the tab header?

I tried to set `ondblclick="return false;"` on both `<rich:tab>` and `<rich:tabPanel>`, but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a popup which shown to user during ajax request. So user cannot click buttons, tabs etc. For example,

```
<a4j:status id="commonAjaxStatus" onstart="javascript:Richfaces.showModalPanel('ajaxLoadingPanel')" 
    onstop="javascript:Richfaces.hideModalPanel('ajaxLoadingPanel')">
    <f:facet name="start">
        <r:modalPanel id="ajaxLoadingPanel" moveable="false" resizeable="false" width="239" height="40" zindex="1000">
            <h:graphicImage  value="../img/ajax-loader.gif" />
        </r:modalPanel>
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="stop">
    </f:facet>
</a4j:status>
```

If you insert this code into your page, on ajax requests a popup will be opened and when the request finishes, popup will disappear.